# Microsoft Graph appRoleAssignment direct queries not supported?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been using these github documentation pages: [Page1](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/approleassignment.md), [Page2](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_get.md), I've implemented adal on the app that I'm using and I'm just logging the token on the console so that I can just copy-paste the token into postman and try requests faster.

I've been trying a get request as mentioned on the documentation to.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appRoleAssignments/{Object Id of AD App} or { App ID of AD App }
```

But also attempted various other routes based on the documention. I'm getting 'resource not found' for all of the other ones and `'direct queries to this resource type are not supported'` for the one above.

Brosed a few related stackoverflow threads and went into github issues to see anything related to approlesassignment resource type but no luck.

EDIT: Token is obtained in Angular app using package [adal-angular4](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4) (it is however an angular6 application and the package has been updated to work with Angular 6)

Comment: Note that if you're using Postman, the easiest approach is to set the Authorization to Type "OAuth 2.0", choose a flow that makes sense (e.g. Implicit, if you're acting link a native client app, or maybe Authorization Code, if you're acting like a web app).

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret hmm -- I'm using postman for testing before implementing on the final app which will be Angular6 web app. But in there I'm setting headers using Bearer + token as well. I have however changed authz to OAuth 2.0 and I'm getting the exact same reply.

Comment: Even when you use the correct request, as you've correctly included it in your self-answer? (By the way, don't forget to accept your own answer!)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Sadly no -- doesn't work by changing to OAuth 2.0 might be that the way I'm getting the token is for Oauth1.0? I'll look into the adal logic for that.

My answer was more of a bypass to the problem, would rather mark your reply as a solution if I get it working as that's the real direct solution to the problem in the title.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to show the code you're using to obtain an access token and to make the request. Otherwise it's very difficult to understand what you need.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I have updated it, I was confusing Oauth2.0 with azure endpoints, I'm using V1 endpoint but from what I'm seeing that is based on Oauth2.0 protocols.

Comment: Can you also include the code you're using to query the Graph API? The GET request you show isn't aligned with your own answer below, so I'm struggling to understand what issue you're facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of struggling, I managed to get the necessary info via Azure Enterprise App API, not th endpoints mentioned above.

This is how the GET request looks like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{ID}/appRoleAssignments/
```

ID in the context above is "Object ID" of the Azure AD App under 'ENTERPRISE APPS', taking the one from under 'enterprise apps' is critical.

You'll find it in:

```
In Azure > Active Directory > Enterprise Apps > Your App > Properties
```

Now you just need bearer authentication token in the header for Microsoft Graph and the right permissions, I think Read/write all directory data should be good enough.

Comment: Isn't the ID `Object Id` in the Properties and not `Group ID`?

Comment: @juunas you are right, I have no idea why I wrote Object ID, must've been distracted. I surely was thinking of Object ID, don't even think Group ID is a thing in this context at all. Have updated my reply. Thanks!

Comment: Also all you should need is Directory.Read.All to perform this GET operation.